# unable to set value into session from a static function in aspx.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, static

hi I am calling a static web method from client side

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static CrmClientReturn check_CrmClient_Exists_With_CrmClient(string Email, string Password)
    {
                    int result = 0;

        try
        {
            result = CommonFunctions.CheckNumberOfEnters();
```

then I am trying to establish how many times the user call this method but all the times I get the Session value for counter as null( even after a few attempts ) what am I doing wrong ??

```
public static int CheckNumberOfEnters()
{
    int result = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    DateTime TimeCounter;
    try
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] != null)
        {
            counter = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"].ToString());
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("counter", counter);
        }
        if (counter < int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginTry"].ToString()) + 1)
        {
            result = 1;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
        }
        else
        {
            if (counter < int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginTry"].ToString()) + 4)
            {
                result = -1;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeCounter"] != null)
                {
                    TimeCounter = DateTime.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeCounter"].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("TimeCounter", DateTime.Now);
                    TimeCounter = DateTime.Now;
                }
                TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - TimeCounter;
                if (ts.TotalMinutes >= int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogINTryMinuts"].ToString()))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeCounter"] = null;
                    result = 1;
                    counter = 0;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLoging.InsertLogError("BasePage.aspx", "CheckNumberOfEnters fail", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**after I upload the code to test site it is working perfectly
but in local host I have the wrong behave 
can some one explain it ??**

Comment: Your server side code is stateless. You need to use a session variable.

Comment: @Donal ham I not doing sow in the CheckNumberOfEnters function ??

Comment: Have you configured it in your web.config - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Donal configured how?? I read the article and find nothing to configure for my case

Comment: Have you debugged the code ? Is there no exception ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad no exception the HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"]  is null all the times

Comment: How are you handling sessions?  Cookies, In-Proc, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, after you increment the counter in the first if block, you need to update the session variable.

Change this:

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] != null)
        {
            counter = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"].ToString());
            counter++;                 
        }
```

to this:

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] != null)
        {
            counter = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"].ToString());
            counter++;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
        }
```

So, CheckNumberOfEnters should look like this (I have tested it and it is working as expected):

```
public static int CheckNumberOfEnters()
        {
            int result = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            DateTime TimeCounter;
            try
            {

                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] != null)
                {
                    counter = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"].ToString());
                    counter++;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                }
                else
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("counter", counter);
                }
                if (counter < int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginTry"].ToString()) + 1)
                {
                    result = 1;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (counter < int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoginTry"].ToString()) + 4)
                    {
                        result = -1;
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeCounter"] != null)
                        {
                            TimeCounter = DateTime.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeCounter"].ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("TimeCounter", DateTime.Now);
                            TimeCounter = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - TimeCounter;
                        if (ts.TotalMinutes >= int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogINTryMinuts"].ToString()))
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Session["TimeCounter"] = null;
                            result = 1;
                            counter = 0;
                            HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] = counter;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLoging.InsertLogError("BasePage.aspx", "CheckNumberOfEnters fail", ex.ToString(), "", 0);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: if you would look a few line down the road you will see that I hade set the counter value

Comment: I have stepped through it in the debugger. It goes into the first if block and does not go into the others. Have you tried the change I have suggested?

Comment: I have tried and its didn't worked properly look at my answer above

Answer (score 0):

Please use int.TryParse instead of int.Parse

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"] != null)
{
     int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Session["counter"].ToString(),counter);
     counter++;
}
```